# Как сделать класс который нельзя инстанцировать(напрямую) но можно использовать его функциональность через наследование

Tags: java

Например есть класс автомобиль(пример кода ниже), не могу понять, как сделать класс который нельзя инстанцировать(напрямую) но можно использовать его функциональность для иерархии.

```
public abstract class Car { 
protected String brand; 
protected String model; 
protected int price; 
protected int maxPassanger; 
protected int capacity; 
protected int velocity; 
protected int maxCarrying; 
protected double fuelConsumption;

public abstract void startEngine();

public abstract void stopEngine();

}
```

Comment: Как вы в наследнике будете использовать приватный конструктор?

Comment: Я навычёк, поэтому простите за глупые вопросы.

Comment: чтобы не повторялись использую приват, вроде так понял

Comment: Покажите пример кода где вы хотите использовать "приватный или абстрактный класс"!

Comment: public abstract class Car {

    protected String brand;
    protected String model;
    protected int price;
    protected int maxPassanger;
    protected int capacity;
    protected int velocity;
    protected int maxCarrying;
    protected double fuelConsumption;

Answer (score 4):

Для иерархии - абстрактный класс. Если конструктор приватный - то невозможно сделать экземпляр этого класса снаружи, в том числе и у наследников

Answer (score 3):

Если конструктор приватный - то невозможно сделать экземпляр этого класса ИЗВНЕ. Но можно изнутри, посредством доступного статического метода. Можно даже наследоваться от этого класса с помощью статического вложенного класса (и тогда объемлющий класс может быть абстрактным). Короче, если конструктор приватный, то данный класс полностью контролирует создание экземпляров этого класса и его наследников.